# Retrieve Response data from another website using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to hit the courier companies website from Controller ( e.g bluedart,fedex etc) by passing the courier tracking number and fetch status of the given tracking number.

I am using  `$HttpSocket->get/post` to hit the webpage URL

I am able to display the response body

How can I fetch the data from the `response`.

Or is there any other way to achieve the same

Please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fetch the data from the response.

Parse the result, either using regular expressions or the DOMDocument class and traverse it. See [Parsing HTML in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623377/parsing-html-in-cakephp) as well.

> Or is there any other way to achieve the same

Use the APIs these companies usually offer.